# "Undefined offset" error in search result

Tags: php

I made a small code to search inside TXT file,
It works, but I got an error in this part of the code:

```
function searchLastName(Array $array, $value)
{
    $lastresult = '';
    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        if (isset($subarray[1]) && stristr($subarray[1], $value) && $value != "") {
            $lastresult .= $subarray[0] . " " . $subarray[2] . " " . $subarray[1] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    return $lastresult;
}

$file = fopen("classlist.txt", "r");
$filestring = "";
while (!feof($file)) {
    $tempstring = fgets($file);
    $filestring .= $tempstring . "<br />";
    $line_of_text .= $tempstring;
}
```

The first error in line 17 "Undefined variable: line_of_text"

The second error in line 5 "Undefined offset:"

**What I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: `$line_of_text .= $tempstring` but you didn't define `$line_of_text` in the first place. As for line 4, you're using `$subarray` as an array and assuming it to have three items, but nothing in the code checks for that to be the case before blindly accessing it.

Comment: Okay I solved one of the problem but "line_of_text .= $tempstring;" I didin't get this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your variable before the while loop:

```
 $line_of_text = '';
```

And the `$subarray` has most likely only one element or two, so key 2 is undefined.

Comment: "has most likely only one element" - on what basis do you make this assumption?

Comment: Exaclty I only have two elelemnt and the second one was undefined, thanks I solved this problem, but what about this one "line_of_text .= $tempstring;" I didin't get this one?

Comment: .= means you concatenate two strings: the 'old' value of `$line_of_text` and `$tempstring`. At the first iteration `$line_of_text` is not defined. Therefore you should add that line before the while loop